# Use Rails datetime to remove event after minutes have passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a trivia game in Rails. Currently, I am limiting who can enter the game to two conditions: a) the game must not have exceeded maximum users (`max`) and b) the registration cannot happen after the start time of the game (`game_start`), which uses a `datetime` value to compare:

```
     <% elsif Time.now > Quiz.where(category: session[:category]).first.game_start or Reservation.where(category: session[:category]).count >= Quiz.where(category: session[:category]).first.max %>
         <p>Sorry, this game is <b>closed</b>. Try again tomorrow!</p>
```

That is working. But it's a game, and just because a user registers before the `game_start`, they could come back many hours later after the game and instead see the `else` condition to enter (in other words, they registered at 4:50, the game starts at 5:00, and they come back at 7:00 and can still play the game, even though all players should have started around 5:00).

To fix this, I want to designate a third `or` condition for `elsif` that a user must also be within, say, 3 minutes of `game_start`.

Right now, I am doing a comparison of `Time.now` to ensure no new registrations come in. Can you designate a "maximum minutes" as well to accomplish this new condition?